# how to configure outlook 2013 with squid

Tags: windows-8, email, microsoft-outlook-2013, squid

I have my work environment where my internet was protected through "squid" , whenever user is connected to internet, he was allowed to pass through only proxy configuration(port 3128).

Is it there any way to configure my Microsoft outlook 2013 to use squid port? any server side configuration needed?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean for retrieving / sending email, or for opening the remote HTML parts of emails when displaying them?

Comment: @Paul yup for retrieving and sending email friend

Comment: _Settings -> Accounts -> Email tab -> select account -> Change -> More settings -> Connection tab -> Outlook Anywhere -> Exchange Proxy settings_.  This is if you're using an Exchange account. For others, it might be different